# Редактор JS/NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide

Кто может посоветовать простой редактор под Win для JS/NODE с подсказками, нашёл www.agpad.com но по ходу так и загнулся на версии 0,1 много лет назад, в Sublime Text под винду тоже рабочего решения нету, то что есть работает кривовато

Comment: Редактор - это среда для написания текста. Sublime, это редактор, Вы в вопросе просите подсказать редактор, но возможности хотите от ide да еще для nodejs. Из ide могу лишь посоветовать phpstorm, он платный. Так же давно сам хочу попробовать бесплатную visual studio. Есть есщё очень интересный вариант с облачной ide-редактором https://c9.io/ он совмещает некоторые возможности sublime + возможности от ide.

Comment: @shatal, [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) тогда уж.

Comment: да ничего я нехочу от IDE, как я уже сказал agpad почти что идеальный вариант как задумка, но он был брошен на альфа версии, IDE мне ненужны, если бы у sublime был нормальный автокомплит то это было бы супер, но SublimeCodeIntel у меня на винде нормально не заработал, да и по отзывам он частенько лепит автоподсказки не всовсем в тему

Comment: А вот теперь подумайте для чего РЕДАКТУРУ ТЕКСТА нужен автокомплит? Автокомплит это уже ide. У sublime нет нормальных автокомплитов, а если ставить сниппеты, то пропадает возможность автокомплита свойств из текущего файла.  А ещё стоит учесть что nodejs это уже прошлое, а на io.js редакторы ещё не знают. И можете ещё попробовать atom.io и потом отписаться как он.

Comment: @shatal , IDE это не автокомплит, это проекты, сборщики и т.д. , как я уже сказал если бы не сырость agpad то было бы супер, Node не прошлый век, благодаря io они начали шевелится , io ещё сыровата, я бы сказал так, для продкшн Node , для себя io

Comment: Ну раз Вы такой умный что не слышите о чем я Вам пытаюсь сказать, то примите за должное, что идеальной среды разработки нет. Или используйте "че есть" или сойдите сума.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пользуюсь [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), для него есть много плагинов на любой вкус, в том числе для node.js

К примеру - *Brackets-Node.js* (Node.js bindings) is an extension for Brackets to run Node.js or NPM files directly from Brackets.

или *Theseus for Brackets* - Theseus is a new type of JavaScript debugger for Node.js, Chrome, and both simultaneously. It is an extension for the Brackets code editor.

Answer (score 2):

Для того же Sublime есть хороший плагин [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/).
Если нужно IDE, то Webstorm тоже очень хорош. Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition тоже позволяет удобно редактировать Node-код.
Я, к примеру, пользуюсь VIM. Для него тоже есть плагины [vim-node](https://github.com/moll/vim-node) и [vim-nodejs-complete](https://github.com/myhere/vim-nodejs-complete).

Answer (score 2):

Так же совсем недавно вышел [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), в который встроена поддержка JS/Node. Еще можно воспользоваться плагином [Tern](http://ternjs.net/), который поддерживают большинство редакторов, включая Emacs, VIM и проч.

Comment: VSC всё таки больше на IDE тянет, хотя я его опробовал почти сразу как он вышел, грузится конечно быстрее чем Eclipse.based но всёравно долговато. хочется чего-то более лёгкого, пока остановился на Sublime

Comment: У меня VSC падает так же часто, как и Atom)

Comment: Ну пока я плотно подсел на Brackets